# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource even after setting CORS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am fed up with CORS error in .NET Core Web API app. I have did all the settings I believe.

Here what I have done

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors(options =>
            options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
        //app.UseCors(builder => builder
        //            .AllowAnyOrigin()
        //            .AllowAnyMethod()
        //            .AllowAnyHeader()
        //            .AllowCredentials());
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

    }
```

Even now its triggering the following error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44331/api/kip' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm calling it from Angular

Here is my calling script

```
  getProjects() {
    let url:string=this.isServer?"http://localhost:51071/webservice1.asmx":"https://localhost:44331";
    console.info(url);
    return this.client.get(url+'/api/kip', {
      withCredentials: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });
  }
```

Also I set a breakpoint at the API last line before returning, it reaches there without any issue. So after calling return it triggers the error. Also I tried the API separately which returns the JSON.

Here is my controller.

```
    // GET: api/Kip
    [HttpGet]
    public KipProjects Get()
    {
        KipProjects proj = new KipProjects();
        kip keyedin = new kip();
        proj=keyedin.getKeyedinReport();

        return proj;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `AllowCredentials` to the one where you are specifying the origins (`options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")`)?

Comment: Yea, that also tried. But result was same!

Comment: Hmm, might be that UseCors needs to be after UseRouting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware) :

> Note: The specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is returned.

So try with `options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`